# offline OSM map for WIndows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, openstreetmap, offline, tiles

For 3 days i am trying to get this working.
I am new to WP8.

I done this on iOS using "route me" Lib by loading tiles.db from this tutorial :

https://github.com/Label305/iOS-OfflineMaps-Example/wiki/Create-database-of-tiles

I am trying to use BruTile/Mapsui.

Even online OSM map will be a big progress to my app.

Maybe some of you guys have simple sample?

Sry for bad Eng i'm still learning :)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Could you give a sample of the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you already take a look at the [list of Windows Phone applications for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Windows_Phone)?

Comment: RobbieE ok i dont have some files there :Mapsui.Rendering.Xaml.dll, Mapsui.UI.Xaml.dll, Mapsui.dll in debug folders. I use VS 2012 for WP.

scai. Yes i saw this but those are for download to phone if i am correct and i want make my own app :)

Comment: I Updated to VS 2013 Professional Trial to test it and i still have problems i dont know but even official sample dont have  Mapsui.UI.Xaml;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this tutorial:

http://kodira.de/2013/01/offline-maps-with-windows-phone-8/